# How to reveal the content of an build-in dataset?

Tags: r, dataset

Many packages in R with build-in datasets in them.(just like “Vehicle” in “mlbench”, and “churn” in C50) We can use `data()` function to load these dataset. Sometimes, I want to check the structure and content of these data set in order to construct a new dataset for further analysis. But the `view()` function offen failed to do this job, `summary()` could use in some cases, but if you use `summary(churn)`, the only result you get is an error: `Error in summary(churn) : 找不到对象'churn'`.
Is there any common methods to reveal a part of the build-in dataset?

Comment: Is there something preventing you from loading the data set, typing `ls()` to get a variable name, and then just inspecting it as you would normally?

Comment: you should use `View()`, not `view()`

Answer (score 1):

Despite the fact that churn.Rdata is in the ../data/ directory of the C50 library, loading it shows that there is no 'churn' object in it. There are, however, both 'churnTest' and 'churnTrain'  datasets and you can see their structure with str():

```
load('/path/to/my/current_R/Resources/library/C50/data/churn.RData')
ls(patt='churn')
#[1] "churnTest"  "churnTrain"
 str(churnTest)

'data.frame':   1667 obs. of  20 variables:
 $ state                        : Factor w/ 51 levels "AK","AL","AR",..: 12 27 36 33 41 13 29 19 25 44 ...
 $ account_length               : int  101 137 103 99 108 117 63 94 138 128 ...
 $ area_code                    : Factor w/ 3 levels "area_code_408",..: 3 3 1 2 2 2 2 1 3 2 ...
 $ international_plan           : Factor w/ 2 levels "no","yes": 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ voice_mail_plan              : Factor w/ 2 levels "no","yes": 1 1 2 1 1 1 2 1 1 2 ...
# snipped remainder of output
```

Would also have gotten some sort of response to:

```
data(package="C50")
```

I get a panel that pops up with:

```
Data sets in package ‘C50’:

churnTest (churn)      Customer Churn Data
churnTrain (churn)     Customer Churn Data
```